# Complicated multiple criteria query in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a complicated query to perform for a spreadsheet configured like this:

```
 A  B  C  D 
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
.. .. .. ..
```

The following conditions must be fulfilled together:

- A is a specific string **foo**
- B must be a specific string **bar**
- C must be TRUE

If all above are not fulfilled at the same time, then give value 3. If the above are fulfilled, but D is not the desired string **foobar**, then give value 2. If all conditions are fulfilled (including D condition), then return 1.

I'm using the following syntax:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1, (A2:A24="foo")*(B2:B24="bar")*(C2:C449=TRUE),0))=TRUE, 3, IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1, (A2:A24="foo")*(B2:B24="bar")*(C2:C449=TRUE)*(D2:D449="foobar"),0))=TRUE, 2, 1))
```

There seems to be an issue with the last "ISERROR". It doesn't return the correct value on its own either.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,(A2:A24="foo")*(B2:B24="bar")*(C2:C449=TRUE),0)),3,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,1*(D2:D449="foobar"),0)),2,1))
```

You don't need to check A,B and C the second time, because the only way it can get to the second IF() is when the correct values were found there.

Edit:  Your formula as posted works correctly, too. But both of these formulas are *array* formulas and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>